# Query on a rare simultaneous processing of interrupts from GIC/NVIC

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization

Let's say the following code is shared by multiple ISRs :

```
   spin_lock_irqsave
   <critical section>
   spin_unlock_irqrestore
```

Also, following sequencing happens (we assume preemptible-interrupts all throughout) :

- Low-priority interrupt comes in, and GIC/NVIC causes it jump to ISR.
- Low-priority interrupt starts executing "spin_lock_irqsave" atomically.
- Before preemption and interrupts could be disabled (by the executing low-priority interrupt), a high-priority interrupt comes in. Since a higher priority interrupt has come in (and preemption and interrupts are still enabled), the GIC/NVIC causes it to forward to software.
- Through the low-priority interrupt executing, "spin_lock_irqsave" has completed (atomically). Preemption and interrupts are disabled, and low-priority interrupt grabs the spin lock.
- Since high-priority interrupt is in software's queue, it preempts the low-priority interrupt in software and spins on the spin-lock.

Is the above sequencing possible?

In other words, although the first interrupt did its best to disable all preemption and interrupts before it could enter the critical section, yet above sequencing **will** cause the high-priority interrupt to spin, thus causing deadlock (since low-priority interrupt has grabbed lock)?

Or software will not allow switching to high-priority interrupt (even though high-priority interrupt is in software's queue) and will instead wait for low-priority interrupt to release the spin lock?

Many thanks in advance for your time for help !

Ajay

Comment: The way it works is 1st disable interrupts, then take the spinlock.  At the end, 1st release the lock, then enable interrupts.  So higher priority interrupt can never come in and deadlock. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h#L104

Comment: Thanks stark for your time.

So once the low-priority-interrupt disables interrupts and acquires lock, high-priority-interrupt will remain in the software's queue but not acquire the CPU (unless the lock is released by low-priority interrupt and interrupts re-enabled)?

Comment: There is no software queue.  Disabling interrupts is a hardware feature.

Comment: Thanks stark.

As per the sequencing in the question, GIC/NVIC can forward two different interrupts of different priorities to software, in case ISR has still not communicated to hardware that interrupts have been disabled. In that queueing of one interrupt (at software side) is the only plausible explanation.

Comment: How would you protect the queue access?  A spinlock?

Comment: I am not an expert stark, but rather wishing for experts' opinions :)

Comment: First answer at the link :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568944/how-interrupt-is-queued-up-in-linux

does specify that interrupts are queued. I guess using spin-lock for queueing would be fine, as spin-lock really needs to be held just to enqueue.

Comment: I guess you didn't read it: `"From the hardware point of view, interrupts are always flagged, not queued, "`